# Inside a jQuery plugin, return 'this' or '$(this)'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When creating a jQuery plugin, what should be returned in a `$.fn` function? Is it `return this` or `return $(this)`? Some of the websites I came across when searching use the former, whereas other websites use the latter:

- `return $(this)`:
  http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx (tip 10)
- `return this`:
  http://devheart.org/articles/tutorial-creating-a-jquery-plugin/

What is the difference, and what is preferred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directly inside of a function which lives on `$.fn` (the prototype of the jQuery constructor), `this` refers to the jQuery collection instance on which the function is operating. Returning `this` is proper. Wrapping it in `$()` just adds unnecessary weight to your code.

See [Context section of jQuery plugin authoring guidelines](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Context).

Comment: Yes, that was what I thought too. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the jQuery object on which your function has been invoked; `$(this)` is a shallow copy of the object (another jQuery object, referring to the same DOM elements or whatever objects the original held). Normally, `this` should be better because 1) creating a copy of the jQuery object takes a nontrivial amount of operations, 2) you don't usually change properties of the jQuery object.

Now if you *do* change properties then the two behave differently:

```
var foo = $('#id');
var bar = $(foo);
foo.baz = 1;
bar.baz; // undefined
```

and in that case returning `$(this)` might make more sense. For example, jQuery's own `add` function does something like this internally:

```
var next = $(this);
// add parameter to next
return next;
```

so when you add an element to a jQuery object, it does not modify the original:

```
var foo = $('html');
var bar = foo.add('body');
bar.length; // 2
foo.length; // 1
```